# Read all files in directory sub folders

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I have a folder - "C:\scripts"

Within "scripts" I have several sub folders e.g. - "C:\scripts\subfolder1" "C:\scripts\subfolder2" etc, that contain `html` files.

I am trying to use the following code -

```
 foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\scripts","*.html"))
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
        }
```

However this does not work due to the `html` files being in the sub folders.

How can I access the html files in the sub folders without having to manually put in the path of each sub folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343.aspx) from DirectoryInfo

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\scripts");
foreach(var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.html",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\scripts","*.html",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Seems to be the right solution for me try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Scripts\\", "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx)

> Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search
>   operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives
>   and symbolic links in the search.

Try like this;

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\scripts");
foreach(var fin d.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{

}
```