# Reading specific files in different subfolders for same line of text C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently creating a short Console Application to read a specific file within multiple subfolders. The file has the same name throughout all the directories, so moving them all to one directory and renaming them would be a huge hassle (there's well over 365 of these files. They are automatically created daily with a new name, and go back a few years). However, they're all under the same main folder.

I have looked into [Read all files in directory sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363478/read-all-files-in-directory-sub-folders#15363601). I understand I'm able to search through each individual subfolder and see all files (I was able to display their `fileName` to console for each one found in my `foreach` statement.

Code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string readLine = string.Empty;
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MotherDir\");
    // foreach loop to go through each subfolder to find FileINeed.txt
    foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("FileINeed.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        //I get an error here: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not file file-'"
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.ToString()))   //this is using the wrong directory, not the one set previously (var dir)
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                readLine = sr.ReadLine();

                ProcessFiles(file.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    Console.ReadKey(); //Gets pause at the end of the program
}

// Method to pass files through in order to search for specific string
static fileEntry ProcessFiles(string fileName)
{
    fileEntry inputFiles = new fileEntry();

    string fileString = string.Empty;
    string readLine;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            readLine = sr.ReadLine();

            if (readLine.Length < 1)
            {
            }

            if (readLine.Contains("RUN DATE: "))
            {
                Console.Write("RUN DATE:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
            if (readLine.Contains("1234567"))
            {
                Console.Write("Found this:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
            if (readLine.Contains("7654321"))
            {
                Console.Write("Found this:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
            if (readLine.Contains("1346785"))
            {
                Console.Write("Found this:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
            if (readLine.Contains("2589632"))
            {
                Console.Write("Found this:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
            if (readLine.Contains("12587412"))
            {
                Console.Write("Found this:    ");
                Console.WriteLine(readLine);
            }
        }
    }

    inputFiles.FileName = fileString;
    return inputFiles; 
}


public class fileEntry
{
    //stores file names and datetimes
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
}
```

I apologize for the awful `if` statements looking for a specific string, I was trying to use a switch/case statement but wasn't able to get it work.

I only need this to output to the console window if it found one of the strings (I'm aware I'm trying to output the whole `readLine`). The purpose of this program is to just see if these strings exist within the files being processed.

I'm still fairly new to C#, and this is one of my first worthwhile programs I have written from scratch. So I apologize for the poor coding practices (if any) as I'm still learning! If you have *any* suggestions or help, it would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I'm needing to clarify anything!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Archer , please see comments in code. I'm currently getting an error on `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.ToString())`. So far, my files are not being processed.

Comment: Yeah thanks - I saw that and deleted my comment.  It might be better if you explained outside the code what the problem is, but at least it's there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unnecessarily using StreamReader there, you should just pass it to your ProcessFiles (not file.ToString() but file.FullName which is the full name and path of file - other is FileInfo object):

```
// foreach loop to go through each subfolder to find FileINeed.txt
foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("FileINeed.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //I get an error here: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not file file-'"
            ProcessFiles(file.FullName);
}
```

Note: Hard to understand purpose of ProcessFiles. ie: Why do you return back files back as you process as a new class? You already have them in the point where you first get the list.

Note2: BTW using dir.EnumerateFiles or dir.GetFiles is a better choice than using Directory.GetFiles especially if you want to also filter on other file properties like (CreationDate, ModificationDate ...).

Another sample:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] searches = { "RUN DATE: ", "1234567", "7654321", "1346785", "2589632", "12587412"};

    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MotherDir\");
    var files = from fi in dir.GetFiles("FileINeed.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                let content = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName)
                // sample filter
                // where fi.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
                where searches.Any(c => content.Contains(c))
                select fi;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    }           
}
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you! I had no idea `FullName` was a property. - ProcessFiles was written for a **completely** different and more advanced program. I merely took it, gutted it and only kept what I thought I needed. I included the class `fileEntry` for the method's creation. I guess I'm unclear on what you're asking in your `Note`. As per `Note2:`, aren't I already using `dir.EnumerateFiles` or am I not understanding something?

Comment: @Symon, no you are using dir.EnumerateFiles, and that is correct. I just meant if you instead try to use Directory.GetFiles then you would get back only a string[] which contains the FullName. In real life, generally a search like this also does add some criteria like where file.CreationDate > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3).

Comment: @Symon, in note I was asking why you are returning back a new FileEntry setting its FileName property to an empty string (looked totally purposeless to me).

Comment: @Symon, I will try to compose a practical sample (thinking the files you search are small text files where doing this wouldn't harm memory - hang on it would take 5-10 mins to write).

Comment: It was being returned back to an empty string because I was using `string.Empty` to initialize the value of the string. Then re-assigning the value later. Unless that's an unnecessary step?

Comment: @Symon, yes unnecessary, because you already know the filename. Just added a sample that returns an IEnumerable where at least one of your search strings is contained.

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The thing that jumps out as wrong is that you're opening each file and passing the file contents to `ProcessFiles`, which actually expects a filename, not file contents.  Try changing the `main()` method to this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // this gets all matching files in a string array...
    string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MotherDir\", "FileINeed.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    // parse the string array and call ProcessFiles for each one...
    foreach (var file in allfiles)
    {
        ProcessFiles(file);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    Console.ReadKey(); //Gets pause at the end of the program
}
```

Comment: Making this as another answer! Thank you for your input. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  You can only mark one answer though, so unless you think this is a more suitable answer you should mark the previous one again.  Your call - just happy to help out :)

Comment: Ah. My bad then! I'm still getting used to marking answers for questions. Thank you! Just let it be known your solution worked as well!

Answer (score 0):

`dir.EnumerateFiles` returns a `FileInfo` object. Use the file.`FullName` property to get the fully qualified path name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your use of

```
file.ToString()
```

which I am not sure what it returns. To get a Stream from FileInfo you need to use

```
file.OpenText()
```

so your failing code will be

```
using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
```

And your ProcessFiles could take a FileInfo instead of a string and you get this

```
static fileEntry ProcessFiles(FileInfo file)
```

If you want to get the full path of your file from FileInfo you can use

```
Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, file.Name)
```